# php script error: no search results or error displayed on the search query

Tags: php

I'm working on a php project and the search function from the database is not returning any results or any error. Below is the code for the search function:

```
function searchweb() {
      console.log("click");

      //e.preventDefault();
      searchWebsite = $("#searchWebsite").val();


      if (searchWebsite == "")
        $("#searchWebsite").focus();
      else {

        console.log("else");

        $("#search").html("Searching..");
        $("#search").attr("disabled", true);

        var excat = "like";
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked'))
          excat = "match";


        $.post("userinput.php", {
          searchWebsite: $("#searchWebsite").val(),
          excat: excat
        }, function (data) {

          console.log("hey"+data);
          populateSearch(data);
          });
        function populateSearch(data){
          data = JSON.parse(data);

          $('#result').empty();
          $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            //console.log(data);
          $('#result').append("<tr>\
                        <td><a href='"+value.website_name+"' target='_blank'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i></a></td>\
                        <td>"+value.website_name+"</td>\
                        <td>"+value.avg_score+"</td>\
                        <td><img class = 'imgs img-responsive center' src='../img/"+value.remark+".png' alt ='"+value.remark+"' />\
                        </td></tr>");


        });
        }



        // console.log(searchWebsite);
        $("#search").html("Search Website");
        $("#search").attr("disabled", false);


      }


    }
```

The 'searchweb' function calls the post method to search in the mysql database. I'm using phpmyadmin for this project. The code for post function in userinput file:

```
if(isset($_POST['searchWebsite'])){

    $searchWebsite = $_POST['searchWebsite'];
    $type = $_POST['excat'];
      $sql = "SELECT * from websites WHERE ";

      //for excact match

      if($type=="match")
         $sql.= "MATCH(tags) Against('$searchWebsite') ORDER BY avg_score DESC";
         //for tags contaionun gthose words
      else
        $sql.= "tags LIKE '%$searchWebsite%' ORDER BY avg_score DESC";


        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if($result){
         $rr = array();
         $i=1;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
           { $rr[] = $row;
        $i=$i+1;}

        echo json_encode($rr);
        }
        else
        {
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Error: '".mysqli_error($db).");</script>";
        }




}
```

Comment: Does it work if you add this line `header('Content-Type: application/json')` line just before doing `echo json_encode($rr)` ?

Comment: Make sure no output is sent to the browser before calling `header()` or otherwise you'll get an error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No error will be spit back as this is a .post in javascript call / AJAX request.  AJAX will not dynamically parse the javascript error code you're trying to trap within the AJAX request.

It's better to do something like this:

**PHP side:**

Replace:
echo "alert('Error: '".mysqli_error($db).");";

With:

```
echo json_encode( [ 'error' => mysqli_error($db) ] );
```

**Javascript Side:**
// Note you shouldn't have to parse JSON since on the PHP side the error array has been encoded as json

```
if( ! $.isEmptyObject(data.error) ) {
    alert( data.error );
}
```

Comment: you can try voting this down but this is the correct answer. lol